# Migrating Configuration - 3750G to 3750X

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands, cisco-3750

What is the best practices to migrate configuration from an older Cisco switch model to a newer Cisco switch model?

-I am not expecting to change any configuration, just simply want to be on the newer non-EOL model

-In my particular situation the older model switch is a 3750G and I will be migrating to a 3750X stack.

-The 3750G switch is using 12.x while the 3750X is using 15.x

Could this be as simple as copying and pasting "show run?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could this be as simple as copying and pasting "show run?"

In general, yes. You will probably need to edit the interfaces because the stackable switches will be something like `GigabiteEthernet1/0/1` (Switch/Slot/Interface), but older switches may be something like `FastEthernet0/1` (Slot/Interface). You can verify the interface name differences ahead of time.

There may also be a few minor things, e.g. trunk encapsulation support (some older switches need to set the trunk encapsulation, but most later switches only support 802.1Q, so the command will error), but they normally do not cause any real problems (assuming you are not using ISL, which newer access switches do not support).

Your best bet is to copy the configuration from an older switch into a text editor, then fix the interface names and try to paste a chunk of lines at a time into an off-line, newer switch. You will see where you get errors, and you can fix those in your text files.